# Show TextInputEditText error when setEnabled(false)

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext

I currently have a TextInput that shows that count needed as an error once a spinner location is selected. That part works, but I would also like the error to show when a location still needs to be selected. When I make the TextInput not editable, the error does not show and I cannot see or click on it. I attempted to use setFocusable(), but that allows the text to be edited.

```
    if (curr_position != 0) {
        quantity_field.setEnabled(true);
        quantity_field.requestFocus();
        quantity_field.setError(quantities[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
    } else {
        quantity_field.setError("Select location first.");
        quantity_field.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Essentially, I would like to disable all parts of the TextInput except the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your `app:errorEnabled="true"` as an attribute of the `TextInputLayout`, and set clickable, cursorVisible, focusable, focusableInTouchMode to false from your xml file?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/quantity_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Location:" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Code:

```
if (curr_position != 0)
    quantity_field.setError("Select location first.");
else
    quantity_field.setError(null); // hides the error and reset the tint
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I attempted to do something similar in Java. I also tried the way you suggested, but it still does not have the desired outcome. I do not want the user to be able to click or enter any data in the quantity field until there is a location selected, but I do want the user to see the error message from quantity. The way that I have handles the first part, but not the second. The way that you suggest handles the second, but not the first.